# Derivations on the spaces of continuous functions form an infinite dimensional vector space(generalized tangent space)

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This question basically asks why the notion of tangent space can't be well-generalized to topological manifolds without coming across the issue of dimension.

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold of finite dimension and $C(X)$ denote the space of continuous functions on $X$. Let $p\in X$.

A linear derivation $v$ w.r.t.$p$ is a linear functional on $C(X)$ satisfying $v(fg)=f(p)v(g)+g(p)v(f), \forall f,g\in C(X)$.

My question is, is the space of linear derivations an infinite dimensional space? I will be happy enough to see a proof for $X=\mathbb R, p=0$(or other special cases that could lead to infinite dimension), but general results will be great.

As we know, if $C(X)$ is replaced by $C^\infty(X)$, then this space is the ordinary tangent space, which is finite dimensional.

Comment: Are the derivations assumed continuous linear functionals?

Comment: @Hellen Good question! Actually in algebra as well as differential geometry derivations are not assumed to be continuous. But if you can prove the stronger results for continuous case or provide a counterexample for it, that will be great!

Comment: In $C(\mathbb{R})$ we have a *cubic* root of the identity $g: x\mapsto x^{1/3}$. Then $v(x)=v((x^{1/3})^3)=x^{1/3}|_{x=0}v((x^{1/3})^2)+(x^{1/3})^2|_{x=0}v(x^{1/3})=0$. From this it follows that $v(f)=0$ for all differentiable functions since $v(a+bx+xh(x))=bv(x)$ for all $h$ with $h(0)=0$.

Comment: @Hellen Thanks! What theorem guarantees the approximation of continuous functions by differentiable functions?

Comment: Weierstrass' theorem gives you that on a compact. To apply it you first need to show that $v(f)$ only depends on the germ of $f$ at $p$.

Comment: @Hellen and then?

Comment: Assume that $f$ is zero in a neighborhood of $p$. Let $g$ be zero outside that neigborhood and non-zero at $p$. Then $0=v(0)=v(fg)=f(p)v(g)+g(p)v(f)=g(p)v(f)$. It follows that $v(f)=0$. This shows that $v$ only depends on the germ of $f$ at $p$.

Comment: @Hellen I meant after we show that $v(f)$ only depends on the germ...how to prove the rest?

Comment: Ah!. Well, work with $C([-1,1])$ instead of $C(\mathbb{R})$. In $C([-1,1])$, all elements are limits of differentiable functions, [polynomials even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: We already proved (without assuming continuity of $v$) that it must vanish on the differentiable functions. Assume $g$ is continuous and such that there is a differentiable function $p$ with $p'(g(0))\neq0$ such that $0=p(g(x))$ near $x=0$. Then $0=v(p(g(x)))=p'(g(0))v(g)$, which implies that $v(g)=0$ too.

Comment: It looks like these derivations, if there are non-zero ones, vanish on too many functions to be useful, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search finds that the question had been answered in [planetmath.org](https://planetmath.org/derivationsonaringofcontinuousfunctions) (The post there concerns with derivations $C(X)\to C(X)$ instead of $C(X) \to \mathbb R$, but the proof is similar). The result is:

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be a topological space and let $C(X)$ be the space of continuous functions to $\mathbb R$. Let $x\in X$ and let $D$ be a derivation at $x$: that is, $D : C(X)\to \mathbb R$ is linear and
> $$ D(fg) = f(x) Dg + g(x) Df, \ \ \ \forall f, g\in C(X).$$
> Then $D(f) = 0$ for all $f\in C(X)$.

The proof goes as follows:

> Lemma 1: For any constant function $c$, $D(c) = 0$. *Proof*: exercise...

From lemma 1, it suffices to check $D(f) = 0$ for all $f\in C(X)$ with $f(x) = 0$. Write $f = f_+ - f_-$, where $f_\pm$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$ respectively. Then
$$ D(f) = D(f_+) - D(f_-)$$
and it suffices to check that $D(g) = 0$ for all nonnegative functions $g\in C(X)$ with $g(x) = 0$.

Write $D(g) = D(\sqrt g \sqrt g)$ and note $\sqrt g \in C(X)$. Using that $g(x) = 0$ and the definition of a derivation at $x$,
$$ D(g) = \sqrt g(x) D(\sqrt g) + \sqrt g(x) D(\sqrt g) = 0$$
and that finishes the proof.

**Remark** When $f\in C^\infty (X)$, $f_\pm$ might not be smooth and thus the argument does not work for $C^\infty(X)$.